# How can I install files into System32 Folder on an 64Bit Platform

Tags: installation, installshield, installscript, installshield-2011

I want to install a .sys file into `%windir%/System32/drivers`

directory on a 64-Bit Platform. The setups works fine under 32-Bit, but when I´m installing on a 64-Bit platform, the setup stores the file under `%windir%/SysWOW64/drivers.`

I tried to install the file under `<Windir>\System32\Drivers`, seems to be the wrong destination.

So my question is, how can i store a .sys file under `%windir%/System32/drivers` on a 64-Bit System without making a new setup?

BTW: I´m using an Installscript Project under Installshield 2011.

Gretings and sorry for bad english ;)

**Resolved!**
I added following code into my Installscript:

> ```
>  function OnBegin()    
>  begin  
>      if (SYSPROCESSORINFO.nProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 || SYSPROCESSORINFO.nProcessorArchitecture = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64) then  
>          Disable(WOW64FSREDIRECTION);  
>      endif; 
>  end;
> ```

This codesnippet will prevent that the installer automatically installs the files under the x64 default system folder. Then I changed the install destination of the component to 
`<WINSYSDIR64>\Drivers` and everything worked fine.

Comment: You should note how you resolved your issue in a self-answer (rather than as an update to your question) and accept it. Otherwise this question continues to appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable [WOW64FSREDIRECTION](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelpnet.installshield.com%2Finstallshield16helplib%2FmergedProjects%2Finstallshield16langref%2FLangrefWOW64FSREDIRECTION.htm&ei=Gin_U8WbH8m5uATdmIDoBA&usg=AFQjCNGivzPdd8jQCZeROyqqghaQHgPrsg&sig2=br2HojgrM1gRbYa9Hzf_6A&bvm=bv.74035653,d.c2E)

This should work !