# Changing INSTALLDIR from registry (working with InstallShield)

Tags: registry, installshield

I'm working with InstallShield and creating an installation that is like an addon. It must read from registry where the program X has been installed and then add the necessary files to the found location.
My problem is this :
On 32bit computer the registry will be found under HKEYLM\Software\X.
On 64bit computer the registry will be found under HKEYLM\Software\Wow6432Node\X.

So how can i read from registry the correct registry value and then set the found value to INSTALLDIR?

Comment: Both registry keys you describe are actually the same path when viewed as a 32-bit key. So just craft your search to look for `HKLM\Software\X` and don't mark it as 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find if the target machine is 64 or 32 bit machine.You can use `SYSINFO.bIsWow64` similar commands. Once found run the reg commands thru IF loop and achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tested it? I think that if you search for the x86-RegKey(HKEYLM\Software\X) you should be redirected to the correct x64-RegKey(HKEYLM\Software\Wow6432Node\X) on x64-systems.

If that doesn´t work try this: [x64-redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176253/how-can-i-install-files-into-system32-folder-on-an-64bit-platform)